# MATLAB reduce function?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, functional-programming

I would like to add a cell array of images together using `imadd`, but `imadd` only takes two arguments. Is there a reduce function in MATLAB which I could use add all of these images together without writing a for loop?

```
images = {im1, im2, im3};
sum = reduce(@imadd, images);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use an array with an extra dimension. E.g. for 2-d (grayscale images)

```
images = {im1, im2, im3};
imarr = cat(3, images{:});
imsum = sum(imarr, 3);
```

Of course there's no need to create the cell array in the first place; you could go straight to

```
imarr = cat(3, im1, im2, im3);
imsum = sum(imarr, 3);
```

or even

```
imsum = sum(cat(ndims(im1)+1, im1, im2, im3),ndims(im1)+1);
```

which also more generally combines any dimensional matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Image Processing Toolbox, the [IMLINCOMB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imlincomb.html) function (linear combination of images) can also be used, just give all coefficients as one:

```
imsum = imlincomb(1,im1, 1,im2, 1,im3)
```